# Fuse multiple data.frame date fields by removing NA using piping

Tags: r, dplyr, piping

I want to fuse multiple date fields that contains NAs using piping in R.  The data looks like:

```
dd <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d"),
                  f1=as.Date(c(NA, "2012-03-24", NA,NA)),
                  f2=as.Date(c("2010-01-24", NA, NA,NA)),
                  f3=as.Date(c(NA, NA, "2014-11-22", NA)))
 dd
  id         f1         f2         f3
1  a       <NA> 2010-01-24       <NA>
2  b 2012-03-24       <NA>       <NA>
3  c       <NA>       <NA> 2014-11-22
4  d       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

I know how to do it the R base way:

```
unlist(apply(dd[,c("f1","f2","f3")],1,na.omit))
          f2           f1           f3 
"2010-01-24" "2012-03-24" "2014-11-22"
```

So that is not the point of my question.  I'm in the process of learning piping and dplyr so I want to pipe this function.  I've tried:

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% mutate(f=na.omit(c(f1,f2,f3)))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `f` must be length 4 (the number of rows) or one, not 3
```

It doesn't work because of the line with all NAs.  Without this line, it would work:

```
dd[-4,] %>% mutate(f=na.omit(c(f1,f2,f3)))
  id         f1         f2         f3          f
1  a       <NA> 2010-01-24       <NA> 2012-03-24
2  b 2012-03-24       <NA>       <NA> 2010-01-24
3  c       <NA>       <NA> 2014-11-22 2014-11-22
```

Any idea how to do it properly?

BTW, my question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008142/combining-more-than-2-columns-by-removing-nas-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106132/combine-merge-columns-while-avoiding-na) as I want to use piping and because my field is a date field, I cannot use `sum` with `na.rm=T`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalesce` to create the new column,

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>%
   transmute(newcol = coalesce(f1, f2, f3)) #%>%
   #then `filter` the rows to remove the NA elements 
   #and `pull` as a `vector` (if needed) 
   #filter(!is.na(newcol)) %>%
   #pull(newcol)
#     newcol
#1 2010-01-24
#2 2012-03-24
#3 2014-11-22
#4       <NA>
```

Comment: It may hasn't been clear, but I didn't want exactly the apply result.  Anyway, you are right on it with the `coalesce` function.  Inspired by your code, `dd %>% mutate(newcol = coalesce(f1, f2, f3)) ` gives exactly what I want.  (you may want to edit your answer, but I'll accept it anyway). Thanks!